# Almost sure convergence of the average of the product of 0-1 random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Assume that $X_n^N$, $n=1,\ldots,N$ for all $N>0$ are 0-1 random variables such that 
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n^N \to p
$$
almost surely. Now, consider $a$ sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $(Y_n)$ with parameter $q$.
It is known that $Y_n$ is independent of $X_n$, and that $X_n$ may depend on $Y_i$ but only if $i<n$.

My question is:
can we conclude that
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n^N Y_n \to pq
$$
almost surely?

**My attempt/note**:  if the LHS would be replaced by expectation, then the result would be true because $\mathbb{E}[X_n Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_n] q$ and 
$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_n] \to p$ by the uniformly integrability of the $X_n^N$. This should also mean that if the random variable $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n^N Y_n$ converges, then it must converge to $pq$. So it would remain to show that it converges.