# Convergence of the average of the product of 0-1 random variables for $\omega$ fixed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Assume that $X_n^N$, $n=1,\ldots,N$ for all $N>0$  and $Y_n$, for all $n>0$, are 0-1 random variables living in the same probability space.
All the $Y_n$'s are independent and Bernoulli with parameter $q$.
Furthermore, for all $n$, $Y_n$ and $X_n$ are independent but $X_n$ may depend on $Y_i$ if $i<n$.

Fix $\omega$ such that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N X_n^N(\omega) = p > 0$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N Y_n(\omega) = q$.

My question is whether or not the following limit holds true:
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n^N(\omega) Y_n(\omega) = p q
$$

My first difficulty is that I don't see how I can use the independence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ to reason $\omega$-per-$\omega$.

Comment: are you saying, for any given sample point $\omega$ where the first two limits hold, you want to see if that means the 3rd limit also holds for that sample point?  if so i think i have a counterexample.

Comment: @antkam yes I'm saying that! I'd be glad to see the counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are still trying to prove your older conjecture raised in: [Almost sure convergence of the average of the product of 0-1 random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742820/almost-sure-convergence-of-the-average-of-the-product-of-0-1-random-variables) (That was an interesting conjecture and I spent some time thinking about it, but to no avail.)  While I believe your older conjecture is true, this current conjecture is false.  (I.e. this approach does not work to prove the older conjecture.)  Sorry...

Counter example for $p = q = 1/2$:

Define a sample point as the sequence $\{Y_n\}$.

Define $X_1 \equiv 1$ and $X_n \equiv Y_{n-1}$.  Clearly $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent.

Consider the sample point of alternating $0$s and $1$s, i.e. $\omega = 01010101010...$  Then the successive $X$s are $101010101...$  We have:

- $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N X_n^N(\omega) = {1\over 2}$
- $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N Y_n(\omega) = {1\over 2}$
- $\forall n: X_n Y_n = 0$ and so $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n^N(\omega) Y_n(\omega) = 0$

Re: your older conjecture, obviously the hope is to show that such counterexamples have zero measure.  Indeed for the specific $X_n \equiv Y_{n-1}$ defined above, your older conjecture should be easily proved in the sense of "almost surely", but just not for EVERY sample point.

Comment: You're right, thank you (and yes as you said I'm still trying to prove my previous conjecture!)